# How to find a lower bound for a sorting algorithm which involves super-comparisons?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Suppose there is a *sorting algorithm* that in addition to regular comparisons, is also allowed super-comparisons: a super-comparison takes in three elements and outputs those elements in order from smallest to largest.

I want to find a lower bound.

Since unlike a regular comparison that only has two possible outcomes, a super-comparison will have 3! possible outcomes, I believe it should be `log3(n!)`.

I am not sure though, any ideas?

Comment: You didn't specify the algorithm. Give us pseudocode otherwise what you ask is called a lower bound for the **problem** which is something different and may require a hard proof depending on the problem.

Comment: I am studying for an exam tomorrow. And this was a question in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the number of super-comparisons is `log_6(n!)`, this is because you have 6 possible outcomes per super-compare op, and not 3 (3! = 6). Thus, by repeatedly invoking these super-comparisons on the tree representing the random permutation, you get to a sorted array within `log_6(n!)` compare ops.

Note that when it comes to *asymptotic* time complexity - it remains `O(nlogn)` the base of the logarithm does not matter because you can switch bases easily:

```
log_6(n!) = log_2(n!)/log_2(6) = log_2(n!) / CONST 
=> log_6(n!) is in O(log_2(n!))
=> log_6(n!) is in O(nlogn)
```

**P.S** A good intuition will be to see what happens at "infinity" i.e. what you have a super-comparison that sorts `n` elements. Obviously, you will need a single such op to sort an array, and indeed `log_n!(n!) = 1`, while `log_n(n!) > 1`.

Answer (score -1):

in ocaml,

```
let rec quicksort = function
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs -> let smaller, larger = List.partition (fun y -> y < x) xs
               in quicksort smaller @ (x::quicksort larger)
```

Comment: How does that answer the question?